# File layout in html and css only or with svg?

Tags: html, css, file, svg, layout

how i can best build a similiar layout? I looked on jsfiddle and other places but could not find anything similiar to modify.

On top of the normal border there is a "second box" just like in a file storage cupboard.
The width of the second box on top should be dynamically set depending on width of the text inside.

Is this approach good? or must i use somehow make a svg file and paint the border of the green circled box  in inkscape? this comes to my second question: how do i assign a svg border to html the best way. With border-image?

```
   .frame{
        border-radius: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(192, 9, 9, 0.7);}
```

[how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAMHx.png)

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the second box could be another div that is positioned absolute. It could have borders on the left, top and right side using `border-left:`, `border-right:`, etc. The larger box can have a border using `border:1px solid black` and the second box can sit on top to overlap part of the border to make it look like the design.  Using a div element positioned like this instead of an SVG will ensure that it will adjust to the size of its contents.

Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/v1zcnf0b/18/

For your second question, the `border-image` property can be used to set an image as a border https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp but for the design that you have shown, I think it would be better to implement with the border and position properties above.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using two elements that overlap. In this example the `.tabrow` is positioned relative and has a negative position to the bottom of -1px. It also has a `z-index` that is higher than the `.content`.

The border of the `.tab` has the width of 0 in the bottom and has a white background so that it hides the underlying border of the `.content`.

```css
.tabrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -1px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tab {
  padding: .2em;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  background-color: white;
}

.content {
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: .2em;
  border-radius: .5em 0 .5em .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabrow">
  <div class="tab">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```